# Performance issue when generating a file with 'type-fest' import

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I am trying to generate some source files using [`ts-morph`](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph), version `15.0.0`.

I am having performance issues that are somehow related to trying to generate an import from `type-fest` library.

- Without this import, the code generation will take about **15s**, which is fine for my case.
- With the import, it will **several minutes at least**, which is not fine for me.

Below is the code that causes the issue. It is called inside a loop (multiple similar files are created). `this.project` is a reference to ts-morph `Project` object which is created without any parameters, just with `new Project()`.

```
    const sf = this.project.createSourceFile(filePath);

    sf.addImportDeclarations([
      {
        namedImports: ['Collection', 'ObjectId', 'OptionalId'],
        moduleSpecifier: 'mongodb',
      },
      {
        namedImports: ['Except'],
        moduleSpecifier: 'type-fest',
      },
      // other imports
    ]);

    sf.addClass({
      // whatever
    });
```

If I comment out the `type-fest` entry, there is no issue. If I change the `moduleSpecifier` value to something else, like `type-fest2`, there are no issues. The issue seems to be exactly with using `type-fest` as a module identifier.

I am unable to provide a minimal example, since this does not seem to occur in isolation - there might be an interaction with the rest of my code, but it is too complicated to put here.

In short:

- The above code is called in a loop (multiple similar files are created), and this performance issue occurs on the second iteration of the loop (when trying to generate the second file).
- Inside that second loop, the code 'hangs' specifically on the `createSourceFile()` call.
- The file name for first source file is `entity.repository.ts`, and for the second file it is `entity2.repository.ts` (I am running this as part of a test).

The same issue occurs with if I change the code to this:

```
    sf.addImportDeclarations([
      {
        namedImports: ['Collection', 'ObjectId', 'OptionalId'],
        moduleSpecifier: 'mongodb',
      },
      // {
      //  namedImports: ['Except'],
      //  moduleSpecifier: 'type-fest',
      // },
      // other imports
    ]);

    sf.insertStatements(0, "import { Except } from 'type-fest';");
```

All I am interested in is creating a specific source file (text), not any kind of source code analysis. I am wondering what could be causing this performance issue, and whether this can be avoided without using some kind of a workaround.